# Crossplatform iphone / Android 2D game engine

Tags: iphone, android, cross-platform, game-engine

I want to write a 2D game for iPhone and Android.
The thing is, it's not a typical arcade game but more of an app with background services / push notifications / google maps interactions / contact list reading. Is there any crossplatform engine that let me use all those features without trapping me completely in their framework ? The game is not CPU-intensive and doesn't really require openGL ( it's more sprite and tweens based ).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.anscamobile.com/corona/

I haven't tried it but you can take a look at it.

Comment: Corona is a great game development tool, but unfortunately it doesn't support the features he listed: no background tasks, no push notifications, no access to the contact list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford, [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com) (a.k.a Airplay SDK) is what you want.